# VBA Using Vlookup to assign Value to ActiveCell, in another referenced workbook

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I've been trying to use vlookup in VBA and it's being quite annoying.

```
ActiveCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(currentrow, 12), currwor.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("R4C3:R160C10"), 6, False)
```

is the code

The main elements I've used are 
currwor which has been set to reference another workbook and I'm looking to use vlookup on the range in there.

However it keeps kicking up an error saying subscript out of range.

I suspect `currwor` is the guilty party in this 
`Set currwor = ActiveWorkbook` (then the workbook in which the above is executed is opened, and that is assigned a workbook name as well.)
I can't use a specific range because I'm trying to perform the vlookup on each cell in a range, and that range changes everytime, and the currwor is to be executed on a particular document I get but the name may vary (format however remains the same.)

Any suggestions on it?

edit: One error is that it's not supposed to be sheet1 but 'Stock Report by Product'. However it's still kicking up the subscript out of range error.

Answer (score 0):

by using `Set currwor = ActiveWorkbook`
you assign currently active workbook to `currwor` however you mentioned prior to that it should be a different workbook? meaning you should have a line `Set currworb = Workbooks("desired workbook name")`?

Comment: Okay so I've got two workbooks - one is the one that is to be updated which I've set as
    Set currwor = ActiveWorkbook
    Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Nilay\Lync Recordings\Quality Control Database.xlsm")
    Set QCs = ActiveWorkbook
Hope that clarifies it a bit.

Comment: but you have it other way around in this code: once you opened **QCs** it becomes active and whichever sheet/cell is active on that workbook will be populated with your formula, which makes a `VLOOKUP` back to **currwor**.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Yes I'm trying to vlookup back to currwor, because I'm trying to extract the updated figures from there into QCs.
However it's apparently out of range.

Comment: Ah! as expected. you need to add a line to go back to currwor first `currwor.Activate`, this will return you back to it, then in whichever cell active it will do your `VLOOKUP`, however in your original line above you need to change `currwor.Worksheets` to `QCs.Worksheets`

Comment: I think I may have confused you.
I want to put the value in an active cell in QCs but to look it up from a database in currwor. Somehow it says that the subscript is out of range though...

Comment: i see. apologies. is there in fact a "Sheet1" in currwor at all?

Comment: Okay - that was a ridiculous mistake. I've renamed it to the actual name - Stock Report by Product so it reads
      ActiveCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(currentrow, 1), currwor.Sheets("Stock Report by Product").Range("R4C3:R160C10").Select, 6, False).

Still it says - subscript out of range.

Comment: remove the `.select` bit after the range in your comment

Comment: I've solved it but thanks for the pointer - that Stock Report by Product bit was the main problem. 

Very idiotic - but I was testing line by line and skipped where it assigned the workbook to currwor!!!! That's why it was out of range.

Comment: no problem. advice going forward, if things like that get stuck, whilst in debug mode check usual suspects in immediate window, i.e.  variables(`?currwor.name`) to make sure they are assigned as you were planning them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - Idiotic mistake. As pointed out the sheet name was incorrect and the problem was that in execution I skipped the bit where the worksheet was assigned to currwor.

Idiotic enough that I should consider deleting this post off here.